# Need a proper input mask for a time field in Microsoft Access

Tags: ms-access, input-mask

My table field is date/time and formatted like this:

```
mm/dd/yyyy hh:nn:ss
```

I want the user to see this (with the space appearing between date and time

```
__/__/__ __:__:__
```

I want an input mask that demands:

- Either 1 or 2 digits for the month
- Either 1 or 2 digits for the dat
- All 4 digits for the year
- SHOWS the space but just jumps over it for the user
- Either 1 or 2 digits for each of Hours, Minutes and Seconds

Further, when setting up a DB, is it just smarter to have two separate fields for Date and Time. A collegue encouraged me to break them out ... seems sensible?

Comment: When I said, "I want the user to see this" the subsequent text got all jumbled.  It should be: 2 Underbars, fwd slash, 2 underbars, fwd slash, 4 underbars, space, 2 underbars, colon, 2 underbars, colon, 2 underbars.  Sorry for awful way of expressing this, but I don't know why typing it in literally in my question caused it to look all jumbled up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

00/00/0000##00:00:00

See the outcome in the image

[image]

Comment: That will work for me ... thanks Sola.

Answer (score 1):

Controlled user input is not an easy task in Access, as it is optimised for the opposite: To be tolerant and accept many input sequences for date and time.

For the cases where controlled input is mandatory, I've written two articles including full code (too much to post here) and demo, that may give you some ideas:

[Entering ISO formatted date with input mask and full validation in Microsoft Access](https://www.experts-exchange.com/articles/24659/Entering-ISO-formatted-date-with-input-mask-and-full-validation-in-Microsoft-Access.html?preview=Eh7VEzgKeXU%3D)

Current code at [VBA.DateEntry](https://github.com/GustavBrock/VBA.DateEntry).

and

[Entering 24-hour time with input mask and full validation in Microsoft Access](https://www.experts-exchange.com/articles/23539/Entering-24-hour-time-with-input-mask-and-full-validation-in-Microsoft-Access.html?preview=uzaB%2Bz7eejg%3D).

Current code at [VBA.TimeEntry](https://github.com/GustavBrock/VBA.TimeEntry).

Comment: Holy Cow.  That was in-depth.  Thank you Gustav.